# What benefits would make humans want to use organic technology?

Tags: technology, future, organic

I’ve been developing an idea for a human civilization that exists thousands of years in the future, and uses purely organic technology.

My question is this. Is there any real benefits or advantages that organic tech has over traditional technology that humans would want to use?

Comment: What is organic technology and how is it different from inorganic technology? The word *organic* has many meanings. (And the opposite of organic is inorganic, or unstructured, or secondary, or unsystematic and so on; but never "traditional". The opposite of traditional is modern, or radical, or novel, but never "organic".)

Comment: Absolutely. Would we get more Gaudi buildings ? https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Gaudi+organic  ... or do you mean all things will be made out of organic substance ? This deserves a further workout. Great idea, though ! Success with editing this question.

Answer (score 5):

Organic tech has several advantages (which can be emulated of course by sufficiently advanced nanotechnology.)

1. It's environmentally friendly, and cheap in terms of elements. Making metallic objects and rubber objects and all sorts of inorganic materials requires digging up the earth to find rare elements and producing dangerous waste. Organic materials can simply be grown from mostly carbon, oxygen, hydrogen, calcium, nitrogen, and phosphorous, a tiny amount of potassium, sulfur, sodium, chlorine, and magnesium, and some trace elements.
2. It's easily adaptable. A house you can grow is one you can alter, with your advanced technology. If you need a new room for a new child you can simply feed it some fertilizer and it can grow it for you within a few days.
3. It's less dependent on supply chains. Inorganic tech tends to require long supply chains to find the rare elements that make it especially functional. Organic materials can be grown from common materials in the ground and air everywhere.
4. It's alive. Organic tech can easily be built with a personality and a function so that it better serves you, and provides good quality of life.

The main disadvantages are these.

1. It's not very good at producing high density high toughness materials. Metals are great for this. This makes war harder.
2. They can't produce ultra powerful computing devices as easily without rare earth elements to make advanced magnets.
3. Life forms tend to be more vulnerable to radiation and heat than inorganic materials.

So, if they have a fairly stable civilization then they could go full or mostly full organic. This keeps the environment safe, reduces dependence on foreign trade, allows for convenient and adaptable technology. It's not so good if they have to go to war, but it's good so long as they're the apex dog of the area.

Comment: Organics are also far more resistant to corrosion, more vulnerable to radiation but less vulnerable to everyday saltwater or rain. which do we run into more often on a habitable planet?

Answer (score 1):

No.

In a way you can imagine, and here I assume - good, wild and powerful creative fantasy on your part - no, organic technology is not preferable compared to technology in a broader sense. Exactly for the reason - if you limit technology, by definition, of organic technology, meaning putting some constraints which make it organic, it - organic technology - becomes a subset of technology in general, and it means regular technology has more options and solutions for all kinds of problems as it is less limited.  It means you can do maximum of what you can for to solve this or another problem, gain this or another benefits, and if we dive a bit deeper, this freedom of choice is what allows to solve problems, which may be insolvable with any other constraint, which would narrow number of available options.

There is another way to look at this problem as well, if by organic technology, you mean restricting materials used for it to be only or mostly organic materials, in more or less regular sense - that obviously is a heavy burden on finding solutions for a lot of things, just because of materials options to begin with and those problems propagate to ability to develop solutions.

Sure, organic technologies were used in the past(long ago, not so long ago, just recently history wise etc.), so as are they used today, and it adds up to your technological tool belt a great deal, and sure, it is useful and convenient in some cases, and sure we will extend the uses in the future for the cases where it is appropriate. But putting square peg in round hole brings nothing good, this or another way.

PS would left a shorter comment on that, but unfortunately WB is broken on mobile for me, and the problem is important enough to write a little bit more on it. In general, I do not recommend repeating mistakes a crowd does with genetically modifying humans for everything. Also I do recommend to investigate topic how do we use biology as of today for making modern stuff, even a cow can be converted in a future in quite good stuff, and some of such stuff was well imagined in old scy-fy, which I recommend also, even if I can't give any particular title atm.

Comment: Although I agree that a subset can never beat a full set, there is still something to say about restriction of technology. If oil suddenly was expensive and difficult to get, how would you still get oil based stuff or alternatives? The lack of such resource and accompanying technology can spark research, creativity and ingenuity. This can eventually propell you further than before. Then you can compare set A with B and see that the restricted technology tree might fare better in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

What meaning of organic do you intend?

Organic is a word with many meanings in different disciplines.  To an artist, for example, organic implies a certain sense of the object springing to life on its own.  It's quite romantic to think a civilization will want this artistic attribute in everything it does.  Let's call this definition a "maybe."

What about chemistry?  Organic chemistry is a very well-defined term, capturing the chemical reactions used by living creatures.  In particular, if I may simply quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_chemistry) on the matter, "Organic chemistry is a branch of chemistry that studies the structure, properties and reactions of organic compounds, which contain carbon in covalent bonding."  Such a sterile definition, but very well bounded.

It's highly unlikely that a future civilization will limit itself to purely organic chemistry.  While life itself proves the astonishing versatility of compounds like proteins, and structures like bones and teeth are truly miraculous, it does have its limits.  There is *no* way organic chemistry is going to get you to space.  If your future civilization is space faring, they didn't do it via O-chem.  There's just not enough specific energy in compounds like fats and sugars to overcome [the tyranny of the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).  And even if this was surmountable, O-chem simply doesn't have anything to compete with our modern light weight metals and ceramics.

Indeed, I would argue humanity departed from this many thousands of years ago, with the first hammer made of a rock and a stick.  It would truly be a challenge to construct a meaningfully human society without it.

There is, however, a concept of organics which gives me pause.  I'll admit right up front that I'm not certain where it leads.  In organic creatures all around, we see a strange division of labor.  The cells of our body have an astonishing level of autonomy.  As I'm typing, they're constantly tuning and repairing.  Some of the cells called neurons are currently working out how much I should be salivating (my dinner is on the stove, presently, and it smells divine!)

This strange view of organics is one where humanity recognizes that the challenges it faces cannot simply be overcome by a unform force of will, driven perhaps by logic.  There are simply too many variables, and it's too darn inefficient to just steamroll them out.  The only path forward would be to distribute the cognitive load.  Let the proverbial cells take care of what they can.

This is the path which leads to many things.  Not just the vanilla organic cells and metabolisms of modern living beings, but strange oddities like clouds of nanobots, and quasi-sentient structures.  These may not always look like flesh and blood, but they do have a peculiar resonance to them.  The structures they use all support the making of local decisions.  One does not make sleek flat surfaces, but smooth curves.

We see some of this already in our design.  No, we don't have nanobot swarms (yet!).  But we see it in the way we design some of our new fangled additive 3d printed devices.  We can shave weight off in ways we never thought of, but it requires optimizers to do it.  The shapes are not simple.  They require local attention to detail, and careful decisions.

[They](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/3d-printed-cast) look... familiar.  Yet alien.  Perhaps they are the art which causes a thousand-year-old human civilization to spring to life in your ideas.

[image: A 3d printed cast, with a very organic feel to it]

Answer (score 0):

#### Self-replication

Non-organic nanobots for medical purposes need specialized factories and must be replenished to make up for lost/destroyed/old nanobots. But a single injection with Bactobot™ (a heavily modified bacterium that almost never mutates into a horrible plague) lasts a lifetime since they can replicate inside the human body.

#### Self-regeneration

Living technology can regenerate itself, reducing maintenance.

#### Specialized AI inbuild

Afraid your toaster's AI might gain sentience and spread all over the internet? Computer based AI has the nasty habit of escaping and enslaving humanity. Much to risky to apply to everyday items. No such risk when the AI is bound to a body.